# Session timeout and csrf token error in Symfony2 forms

Tags: php, forms, symfony, csrf

I'm facing the 'CSRF token invalid, please resubmit the form' issue when a user has a page displayed for longer than the session expiry and then try to submit the Symfony form. It throws token mismatch at the form validation step in my Symfony controller. How do you guys handle this? How can I catch it ? Do I have to activate csrf validation no matter what or is there certain type of forms which don't need that verification ?

I just saw that people recommend to set the Symfony session timeout to 0 in the config.yml. Is that a good way to prevent this ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some code

Comment: It's not code related, I mean take any Symfony form type, controller and a twig to render that and you will get csrf protection by default. My question is, for what kind of form is required (only login/register forms ?), can I desactivate it for certains forms, how to catch this error and at which level ?

Comment: I usually do it for All forms after user logged in. For handling csrf   http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#csrf-protection